# How do I unzip a file from memory (not a disk file) in Meteor?

Tags: file-upload, meteor, stream, zip

The sequence of events that I'm trying to make happen in Meteor is:

1. On the client browser, upload a zip file and send it to the server
2. On the server, receive the zip file and hold it in a memory object
3. Unzip the memory object into individual objects representing the contents
4. Process the individual files one at a time
5. Return success/failure status to the client

I have steps 1 and 2 working, using EJSON to stringify the contents of the zip file on the client and again to convert it back to its original form on the server.  The problem I'm encountering is when I try to unzip the object on the server.  It seems that every unzip library available wants to operate directly on a file or stream, not on a memory object.

I suppose I could write the object to disk and read it back again, but that seems like an unnecessary step. Is there a library available to unzip a memory object?  Alternatively, is there a way to create a stream directly from the object that I can then feed to the unzip routine?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `unzip` module from npm.  It accepts streaming input and allows you to process output without saving to disk.

It will take some work to wrap it to work with meteor.  Your two options are the `meteorhacks:npm` package or upgrading to the Meteor 1.3 beta.